# Automatically generating PTR records in reverse lookup zone

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, python, reverse-dns

I am working on setting up DNS in our environment. In the test bed, I was creating some `A` records and `PTR` records in the forward and reverse lookup zone files. So, I was wondering instead of adding the records manually in two places, will we able to generate the `PTR` records programmatically based on the `A` records mentioned in the forward lookup zone file.

Does anyone have inputs on how this can be done?

FWIW, I did come across this script `mkrdns.pl` from http://www.mkrdns.org/ but that script is throwing below error message. I tried looking around but in vain.

Seems the script is not in active development as the last stable version was released way back in 2002.

```
./mkrdns-3_3.pl -d /etc/named.conf 

<snip>
(debug) Network "arpa.ip6.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1", View "default", File "/var/named/dynamic/named.loopback", Type "master".

(fatal) The zone file "/var/named/dynamic/named.loopback" is being used by two zones!  Error in config file!

(default:1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa and default:1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa ...)
```

Comment: Write a script which reads each `A` record and creates a corresponding `PTR` record. That's not rocket science, at least try to solve it on your own. It's worth it! Besides: The output does seem to be a `AAAA` record..

Answer (score 0):

I came across [dnsrev](https://wilmer.gaa.st/main.php/dnsrev.html), which walks you through generating reverse zones from your forward zones using `dnsrev`. It takes a bit of setup and it isn't pretty, but it appears to be more recent than the `mkrdns` solution.

My suggestion would be if possible, use [PowerDNS](https://www.powerdns.com/auth.html) with the PowerAdmin web frontend instead. PowerAdmin makes managing DNS much easier in general in my experience, and it allows you to auto-generate PTR records simply by clicking a checkbox when you create a record.

Comment: "This link" above is no longer valid. In the end, it points to a still existing website here, which provides the most important part: the underlying script: https://wilmer.gaa.st/main.php/dnsrev.html